# Ayuda, no puedo conectarme desde Netbeans con Sql Server

Tags: java, sql-server, webservice, netbeans-8.2

He estado realizando varios intentos pero no ha resultado.

Mi cadena de conexión es esta:

```
public String conectar() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=prueba;integratedSecurity=true;";
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        Sentencias = conexion.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        return "Conectado.";
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        return "Error.\n"+ ex.toString();
    }
}
```

También estoy realizando esto desde un web service. Este es el método para llamarlo:

```
    Conexion cnn = new Conexion();
    String rs = "B";
    try {
        rs = cnn.conectar();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ServicioWeb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return rs;
```

Pero me aparece este error:

```
"Error. com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: No se pudo realizar la conexión TCP/IP al host localhost, puerto 1433. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verifique las propiedades de conexión, compruebe que hay una instancia de SQL Server ejecutándose en el host y aceptando las conexiones TCP/IP en el puerto y compruebe que no hay ningún firewall bloqueando las conexiones TCP en el puerto."."
```

Uso sql server 2014 express

Comment: Revisa que tu Sql Server esté bien configurado

Comment: te deja conectar por medio del sql manangeR?

Comment: Este video puede ayurarte paso por paso https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNqLia7rIPM

Comment: También checa si no tienes algún antivirus que esté bloqueando el puerto.

Comment: Como bien te dice el error lo primero es comprobar que tengas la instancia de sqlserver ejecutandose, que tengas abierto el puerto 1433 a conexiones TCP/IP (Sin bloqueos), y que las propiedades sean correctas. Puedes intentar acceder mediante IP local en vez de usar el alias localhost (Doy por hecho que ambos corren en la misma maquina). ¿No estas utilizando usuario y contraseña para la conexión? En tu caso no se los estás enviando.

Comment: Ambos están en la misma maquina y es mediante autenticación de Windows.

Comment: Estás seguro que no te está actuando el firewall de windows o un antivirus?? tiene pintón, o que ha muerto el proceso del servidor y no está levantado..

Comment: Disculpen la demora, seguí el video que me dejó Crying Freeman y funcionó correctamente, no tenía bien configurado Sql Server. Muchas gracias.